# Chaining Independent Observables

Tags: rx-java

id like to do something similar to this: http://joluet.github.io/blog/2014/07/07/rxjava-retrofit/

I have 3 rest calls.  The first feeds into the second.  However, nothing feeds into the 3rd call.  I just need to make sure it runs after the second does.  So im looking for something like a "chain" method here:

```
result1Observable.subscribe(new Observer<result1>() {
    @Override public void onNext(result1 firstRestCallResult) {
        restCall2(firstRestCallResult).chain(restCall3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `restCall3` presumably doesn't return anything so the usual `map`, `flatMap`, etc. operators might be a little tricky to work with - the types aren't going to line up.

A little ugly, but could potentially use the `mergeWith` operator. Your `restCall3` would just call on `onCompleted()`, emitting no values. Keeping things within the `Observable` chain should ensure that if any of the operations either errors or fails to complete the entire chain would error or fail to complete (including `restCall3`).

```
public Observable<UserStatus> execChain() {
    return login()
            .flatMap(responseBody -> getUserStatus(responseBody)
                    .mergeWith(restCall3()));
}


public Observable<ResponseBody> login() {
    ...
}

public Observable<UserStatus> getUserStatus(ResponseBody responseBody) {
    ...
}

public <T> Observable<T> restCall3() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
            //execute blocking call
            performRestCall();
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```

**[Note: I haven't actually tried the preceding code]**

I'm assuming that it's important to you that `restCall3` completes successfully. If you don't particularly care, you could probably `flatMap` the first two `Observables` and use `doOnCompleted` and Rx should ensure that it *only* gets called if both of the preceding `Observables` complete successfully.